# UI Router nested views

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've tried with various anwsers without any luck.

I have this two ui-views:

```
<div ui-view class="expand"></div> //Inside index.html

<div ui-view></div> //Inside home.html
```

And this is my routing:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                views: {
                    '@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
          .state('clients', {
              url: '/clients',
              views: {
                  '@home': {
                      templateUrl: 'app/components/clients/clients.html',
                      controller: 'ClientsCtrl'
                  }
              }        
          })
```

I've tried putting names on the view and calling them in different ways but clients.html never gets display even though the route url changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with the view syntax that you're using with `$stateProvider`. I'll give you two versions, the first will seem very similar to your example and the second is more aligned with best practices.

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('base', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'views/base.html'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            parent: 'base',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            parent: 'base',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
        })
```

Best practice version:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.core')
    .config(stateConfig)
    .run(errorHandler);

stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];
getZipCodes.$inject = ['googleMapService'];
errorHandler.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'logger'];

function stateConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider.state('core', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/core/core.html',
        controller: 'CoreController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
            getZipCodes : getZipCodes
        }
    })
}

/** @desc: Ping the back-end for a JSON object that will be converted into an array of NYC zip codes */
function getZipCodes(googleMapService) {
    return googleMapService.getZipCodes();
}

/** @desc: $stateChangeError handler */
function errorHandler($rootScope, logger) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (error, event) {
        if (error) { logger.error('Error while changing states', error); }
        if (event) { logger.error('The event that caused the error', event); }
    })
}
})();
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad that it worked :D
If you want some extra credit, I would try to refactor your current solution to the best practice version. Here is a link for reference:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: I also wanted to add that it you should definitely have some sort of error handler in place. It'll make debugging much easier going forward. I'd imagine that you must have been overwhelmed with frustration while looking at a blank page with no error messages.

    `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (error, event) {
        if (error) { logger.error('Error while changing states', error); }
        if (event) { logger.error('The event that caused the error', event); }
    })`